Button click not registered nextjs shadcn
Hi i am currently working on project where on button click the front end send request to backend and runs a function. I use shadcn default button in my code with onClick event, when i run code on localhost on my pc it works without any problem, but when i host it on vercel and open it on my iphone the button dosen't work properlly. When it open on iphone sometimes i need to click button 1 time and the function runs sometimes i need to click up to 10 times before the function runs. Does anyone have salutio for this problem?
Here is the code, the button i am talking about is "Print label" button
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import {
    Dialog,
    DialogContent,
    DialogDescription,
    DialogHeader,
    DialogTitle,
    DialogTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dialog";
import { Separator } from "@/components/ui/separator";
import {
    Card,
} from "@/components/ui/card";
import { Package } from "lucide-react";
import { Badge } from "@/components/ui/badge";
import { Orders } from "@/lib/types/shipmondo";
import { FurfillOrder, PrintLabel, createSale, findId } from "./actions";
import { Product } from "@/lib/types/wix";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Progress } from "@/components/ui/progress";
import { Checkbox } from "@/components/ui/checkbox";

export default function Dialogt({ order, totalWeight, products }: { order: Orders, totalWeight: number, products: Product[] }) {
    const router = useRouter();
    // const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
    const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState<number[]>([]);
    const [isPacking, setIsPacking] = useState(false);
    const [isButtonDisabled, setIsButtonDisabled] = useState(false);
    const [packingStarted, setPackingStarted] = useState(false);

    const furfillOrder = async (item_id: number, order_id: number, item_quantity: number) => {
        await FurfillOrder(item_id, order_id, item_quantity);
    }

    const handleCheckboxChange = (index: number, item_id: number, order_id: number, item_quantity: number) => {
        setCheckedItems(prevCheckedItems =>
            prevCheckedItems.includes(index)
                ? prevCheckedItems.filter(item => item !== index)
                : [...prevCheckedItems, index]
        );
        furfillOrder(item_id, order_id, item_quantity);
    };

    const calculateProgress = () => {
        const itemCount = order.order_lines?.filter((line: any) => line.line_type === "item").length ?? 0;
        return (checkedItems.length / itemCount) * 100;
    };

    const handelShippingDicount = async (order_id: number, discountId: number, shippingId: number) => {
        console.log(order_id)
        await furfillOrder(shippingId, order_id, 1);
        if (dicountId && dicountId.length > 2) {
            await furfillOrder(dicountId, order_id, 1);
            console.log(order_id)
            console.log("Allt är klart")
        } else {
            console.log("Fanns inge discountId")
            console.log(order_id)
            console.log(dicountId)
        }
        setIsButtonDisabled(true);
        console.log(calculateProgress());
        setPackingStarted(true); // set packingStarted to true
    }


    // const packad = async (order_id: string) => {
    //     await putStatus(order_id);
    //     setIsPacking(true);
    // };

    // const handleClose = () => {
    //     setIsOpen(false);
    // };

    // const cancelOrder = async (order_id: string) => {
    //     await cancel(order_id);
    //     handleClose();
    // };

    const [isPrinting, setIsPrinting] = useState(false);

    const print = useCallback(async (order_id: number) => {
        if (isPrinting) return; // prevent multiple clicks
        setIsPrinting(true);
        await findId(order_id);
        setIsPrinting(false);
    }, [isPrinting, findId]);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isPacking) {
            router.push('/packning/packas');
        }
    }, [isPacking, router]);

    let shippingId: any = '';
    let dicountId: any = '';


    return (
        <Dialog>
            <DialogTrigger className="h-32 w-10 items-center justify-center flex bg-blend-overlay bg-transparent ">
                <Package size={30} />
            </DialogTrigger>
            <DialogContent className={'g:max-w-screen-lg overflow-y-scroll max-h-screen pb-10'}>
                <DialogHeader className="m-4">
                    <DialogTitle className="items-center flex justify-around">
                        Order {order.order_id.substring(0, 12)}
                        {/* {order.order_status === "on_hold" ? <Badge className="bg-[#ffA500] text-black">Påbörjad</Badge> : <Button onClick={() => packad(order.id)}>Packa</Button>}
                            {order.order_status === 'on_hold' ? <Button
                                onClick={() => cancelOrder(order.id)}
                                variant={'ghost'} color={'destructive'}>Avbryt
                            </Button> : ''} */}
                    </DialogTitle>
                </DialogHeader>
                <DialogDescription>
                    <Card key={order.id} className="flex items-center p-6 rounded-lg border-none m-4">
                        <div className="flex flex-col items-start gap-4">
                            <div className="flex flex-col items-start gap-1">
                                <h3 className=" font-bold">
                                    {order.ship_to.name}
                                </h3>
                                <div className="flex items-center gap-2 text-muted-foreground">
                                    <span>Id: {order.order_id.substring(0, 12)}</span>
                                    <div className="h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-muted" />
                                    <span>Vikt: {totalWeight.toFixed(2)}kg</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
                                {order.order_status === "open" ? <Badge variant={'destructive'}>Ska packas</Badge> : <Badge className="bg-[#ffA500] text-black">Påbörjad</Badge>}
                                <div className="text-base">Artiklar: {`${order.order_lines?.length ?? - 1}`}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Card>

                    {order.order_note && order.order_note.length > 1 ? (
                        <Card key={order.id} className="flex p-6 rounded-lg border-none m-4">
                            <h2 className="w-full">
                                {order.order_note}
                            </h2>
                        </Card>
                    ) : (
                        <Card key={order.id} className="flex p-6 rounded-lg  border-none m-4">
                            <h2 className="w-full">
                                inga anteckningar
                            </h2>
                        </Card>
                    )}

                    {order?.order_lines?.map((line: any) => (
                        <>
                            {line.line_type === "shipping" && (
                                <Card key={order.id} className="rounded-lg border-none m-4 flex p-6">
                                    <span className="font-semibold">
                                        Frakt:
                                    </span>
                                    {line.item_name}
                                    <div className="hidden">
                                        {shippingId = line.id}
                                    </div>
                                </Card>
                            )
                            }
                            {line.line_type === "discount" && (
                                <Card key={order.id} className="rounded-lg border-none m-4 flex p-6">
                                    <h2 className="w-full">
                                        <span className="font-semibold">
                                            Rabatt:
                                        </span>
                                        {line.item_name}
                                        <div className="hidden">
                                            {dicountId = line.id}
                                        </div>
                                    </h2>
                                </Card>
                            )
                            }
                        </>
                    )
                    )}
                    <Button
                        disabled={isButtonDisabled}
                        onClick={() => handelShippingDicount(order.id, dicountId, shippingId)}
                        className="w-full bg-transparent border-[#4BB543] border-4 hover:bg-transparent text-black "
                    >
                        Börja packa
                    </Button>
                </DialogDescription>
                <Separator />

                <DialogHeader className="pb-10">
                    <DialogTitle className="m-2">Produkter</DialogTitle>
                    {calculateProgress() < 100 ? (
                        <Progress className="sticky top-4 sm:top-8 md:-6 shadow-2xl w-full" value={calculateProgress()} />
                    ) : (
                            <Button className="bg-[#00FF00] font-semibold p-8 text-black text-base hover:bg-cyan-500" onClick={() => print(order.id)} disabled={isPrinting}>
                                Printa label
                            </Button>
                    )}
                    {order?.order_lines?.filter((line: any) => line.line_type === "item").map((line: any, index: number) => (
                        <button
                            key={index}
                            onClick={() => handleCheckboxChange(index, line.id, order.id, line.quantity)}
                            disabled={!packingStarted || checkedItems.includes(index)} // conditionally disable the button
                        >
                            <Card
                                className={`flex items-center p-6 mb-4 rounded-lg shadow-lg mt-4 active:border-6 active:border-green-600 ${checkedItems.includes(index) ? " border-4 border-[#4BB543] cursor-not-allowed" : ""
                                    }`}
                            >
                                <div className="flex flex-col items-start gap-4 w-full">
                                    <div className="flex flex-col items-start gap-1">
                                        <h3 className=" font-bold">
                                            {line.item_name}
                                        </h3>
                                        <div className="flex items-center gap-2 text-muted-foreground">
                                            <span>Id: {line.id}</span>
                                            <div className="h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-muted" />
                                            <span>Vikt: {line.unit_weight}gr</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="flex items-center gap-4 font-bold ">
                                        <div>{Math.floor(line.quantity)} st</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </Card>
                        </button>
                    ))}
                </DialogHeader>
            </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
    )
}


If you have figured out how to get the button click to work, can you share it please? I'm having the same issue. I have a shadcn Button in one of my Dialog, the dialog has no form, but a single-row selection table. the table row selection works fine. Just clicking on the Button has no effect. The click handler I added to the Button is not triggered, and I cannot find it in the rendered browser DOM. (the Button is outside of the table)

I have similar problem with shadcn Button on a Dialog without a Form. I cannot hook up the button click event handler in regular approach, like adding the addClick / addClickCapture attribute to the Button element.
I already had a ref to the Button, I use the ref in my table's RowSelectedEvent handler to enable/disable the Button.
This is the two components in my dialog (the inline onClick (or onClickCapture) handler does not work):
<div className={cn("flex justify-end")}>
     <Button ref={ref} disabled={!projectSelected}  onClick={()=>console.log("confirmed")}>Confirm selection</Button>
</div>
<SingleSelectionProjectTableWithAgGrid fetcher={projectsFetcher} rowSelectionHandler={onSelectionChange} />

My workaround is in the rowSelectionHandler:
const ref = React.useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null)
const [projectId, setProjectId] = React.useState<string>()
const onSelectionChange = (evt) => {
    if (ref.current) {
        setProjectId(evt.data["id"])
        ref.current.disabled = !evt.node.selected
        ref.current.onclick = () => console.log("Comfirm button clicked")
    }
}

